# NodeJS validation library for json objects

Tags: json, node.js, validation, jsonschema, ajv

I need to validate some object in my NodeJS app. I have already used an awesome library [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator), it works perfectly, but now I need to validate different object, not only requests and as far as express validator leverages `validator` library, that in turn doesn't support types other than the string type.

I have found different variants like [Jsonschema](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema), [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)

They offer great features, but I need to be able to set error message and than just catch an exception or parse it from return object.
Like that

```
 var schema = {
    "id": "/SimplePerson",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {"type": "string", "error": "A name should be provided"},
      "address": {"$ref": "/SimpleAddress"},
      "votes": {"type": "integer", "minimum": 1}
    }
  };
```

So I can set an error message for every property.

Is there any existing solution to achieve this functionality  ?

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I have found a great library [JSEN](https://github.com/bugventure/jsen) It provides necessary features.

Answer (score 7):

Three powerful and popular libraries you can use for JSON validation are

**AJV:** https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

**JOI:** https://github.com/hapijs/joi

**JSON validator:** https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema

All of these libraries allow you to validate different data types, do conditional validation, as well as set custom error messages.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use Joi library :
https://github.com/hapijs/joi

This library is well maintained, used and offer lots of flexibility and possible actions.

Example :

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().error(new Error('A name should be provided')),
    address: Joi.ref('$SimpleAddress'),
    votes: Joi.number().min(1),
});

// Return result.
const result = Joi.validate(yourObject, schema);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Json Pattern Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpv)

```
 npm install jpv --save
```

usage

```
  const jpv = require('jpv');

  // your json object
  var json = {
      status: "OK",
      id: 123,
      type: {}
  }

  // validation pattern
  var pattern = {
      status: /OK/i,
      id: '(number)',
      type: '(object)'
  };

  var result = jpv.validate( json , pattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [nonvalid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nonvalid), a library that supports callback-based validation with custom checks and errors (disclaimer: it is written by me).

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to embark on validation of JSON submissions to my web service and will be using [tcomb-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcomb-validation).  It's a lightweight alternative to JSON schema and is based on type combinators.

Example of '[intersections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcomb-validation#intersections)':

```
var t = require('tcomb-validation');
var Min = t.refinement(t.String, function (s) { return s.length > 2; }, 'Min');
var Max = t.refinement(t.String, function (s) { return s.length < 5; }, 'Max');
var MinMax = t.intersection([Min, Max], 'MinMax');

MinMax.is('abc'); // => true
MinMax.is('a'); // => false
MinMax.is('abcde'); // => false
```